# "The syntax of the command is incorrect" error when printing a pipe

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script that simulates a progress bar, using `|` characters to show progression.

Unfortunately, whenever I try to show the progress bar, I get the error "The syntax of the command is incorrect." What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
@echo off
color 0F
mode con: cols=51 lines=18
cls
echo                   _____________
echo.                  |
echo                   _____________
```

Comment: -1 for the absolutely useless question title and for not providing a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: @aschipfl - I've reduced the question to the essentials. Hopefully OP's next question is more direct.

Comment: @SomethingDark, thanks, but the problem is now that the already available answers do no longer perfectly fit the question...

Answer (score 3):

You're using the pipe character (|), but that won't work. You have to escape it with ^.

```
@echo 
color 0F
mode con: cols=51 lines=18
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|
echo                   _____________
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                      COMPLETE
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                      
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                      
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                      COMPLETE
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
echo.                  ^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|^|
echo                   =============
cls
```

Answer (score 1):

There are techniques to avoid repainting a screen over and over.
The set /P (input) command allows echoing without a crlf.

Any letter key will abort the loop.

```
@echo off
color 0F
mode con: cols=51 lines=18
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo                   =============
echo                   Initializing.
echo                   =============
echo.
echo                   _____________
Set /p _=".                 "0<NUL
For /L %%A in (1,1,20) Do (
  Set /P dummy=^|<NUL
  CHOICE /T 1 /C 1ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ /D 1 >NUL
  if errorlevel 2 goto :Eof
)
```